# C++ non-static function variables behaves like static variables

Tags: c++, static

I am trying to understand the differences between C++'s static and non-static variables by printing out their memory location during code execution. Below is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

void testStatic(int currNum)
{
    static int counter;
    std::cout << "Address of counter: " << &counter << "\n";
    counter += currNum;
    std::cout << "counter: " << counter << "\n";
}

void testNonStatic(int currNum)
{
    int nsCounter;
    std::cout << "Address of Non-static counter: " << &nsCounter << "\n";
    nsCounter += currNum;
    std::cout << "Non-static counter: " << nsCounter << "\n\n";
}

int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        testStatic(i);
        testNonStatic(i);
    }
}
```

As per my understanding, static variables the memory allocation of static variable will happen once in our case here, where the address of variable remains the same throughout the program's execution time.

For the case of non-static variable (nsCounter), it seemed to behave like static variable as well (same storage, counter keeps updating throughout the loop).

Do I need to initialize nsCounter to 0 every time we call the function to make it non-static?

```
Address of counter: 0x558b476c9158
counter: 0
Address of Non-static counter: 0x7fff20471894
Non-static counter: 0

Address of counter: 0x558b476c9158
counter: 1
Address of Non-static counter: 0x7fff20471894
Non-static counter: 1

Address of counter: 0x558b476c9158
counter: 3
Address of Non-static counter: 0x7fff20471894
Non-static counter: 3

Address of counter: 0x558b476c9158
counter: 6
Address of Non-static counter: 0x7fff20471894
Non-static counter: 6

Address of counter: 0x558b476c9158
counter: 10
Address of Non-static counter: 0x7fff20471894
Non-static counter: 10
```

Expecting non static counter to have the output of 0,1,2,3,4, we got 0,1,3,6,10 here instead.

Comment: The local `int nsCounter` is uninitialized.

Comment: Behaviour of the non-static version is undefined, since `nsCounter` is not initialised.   You are incorrectly assuming non-static variables are initialised to zero by default.

Comment: Memory addresses are a poor proxy for object lifetime.  If you destroy and re-create an object over and over again, it can easily end up in the same place every time purely by coincidence.

Comment: Call your methods from both main() and another method called from main(). You’ll see a difference.

Comment: If you always call the function the same way there's no reason for it to do something different. Call it from another function that's called from `main`, for example.

Comment: Somebody close-voted for "typo". I would appreciate an explanation of that, because that is not the right action for "there is UB" (which I speculate is the reason for the close-vote).

Comment: code.c.c If you fix the UB and otherwise follow the recommendation by user207421 and Pete Becker you should be able to create an answer here. And it might be useful, because I think I have seen this kind of question mutltiple times, but never nicely answered. Everybody feel free to provide a good link for my duplicate library otherwise.

Comment: The second one to close-vote "typo" is also cordially invited to explain.

Answer (score 1):

Non-static variable WITHOUT initializing, its initial value is undefined. Just inialize it.